# speedup and improve chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I recently switch my plugin chart library from highcharts to chartjs.
Everything works quite well but something is not perfect.

The tooltips are pretty slow and not reactive as before. And sometime only the tooltip border remains open. Also the initial animation is laggy.
I know I'm working with a lot of data, but highcharts was really fast.

It seems something is very slow and not optimized.

Can you help me to improve the reactivity?

here a demo: https://devfarm.it/wp-gpx-maps-demo/

Comment: did you check performance? chrome provide performance monitoring options which can suggest you where performance is lagging?

Comment: Yes, I can't see anything suspicious, maybe is only chartjs animation slow

Comment: yes, animation frame firing is taking much time, which is causing the lag.